# JTextField в Eclipse

Tags: gui

подскажите пожалуйста какие есть методы в эклипс для добавления текста в JTextField в заданную позицию.

это мне нужно для организации программы-калькулятора, чтобы при нажатии кнопки цифры, операции на экран в определенную позицию прилагался соответствующий символ или набор символов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

позицию надо указывать вручную (выставлять курсор) или добавление должно происходить всегда в конец строки?

если в конец строки, то примерно так:

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
String s;

//код

s = s + getSymbolFromKbd();

tf.setText(s);
```

Comment: спасибо за решение, но хотелось би узнать есть ли метод для вставки в  заданую позицию

Comment: тогда, получается, нужно получить текст из поля (getText()), затем получить положение курсора, и с этим работать. Строку - в символьный массив, использовать положение курсора при работе с индексами и т. д. Может и по-другому можно, но соответствующих методов я вчера не нашёл